# aws cli - exchange existing security group for a different one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a AWS EC2 instance in the *stopped state* that has a security group attached to it. I would like to use the CLI to drop that group from the instance and attach a *different* security group.

Note I have a specific need to exchange the SG to a different SG and not edit the existing rules on the current one.

Is this possible ? I need to do this for tens of instances and would rather not do this via the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [modify the security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html) on an EC2 instance from the awscli as follows:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-abcdef --groups sg-xxx sg-yyy
```

Comment: That adds the second group without dropping the first so now i-abcdef  has SG sg-xxx AND sg-yyy

Comment: It changes the security  groups of the instance to the provided list.

Comment: Right you are !! Thanks so much !